# Can I sort and limit InfluxDB data to control its display on Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm currently displaying data from InfluxDB in Grafana with a simple query. I'd like to add two features to the query:

- Limit the number of displayed figures to the 3 with the highest last value
- Sort the columns so that the ones with the higher last values are displayed left to right in descending order.

My current query is:

```
from(bucket:"watch-hub")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "status" and r._field == "pull_count" )
```

Which gives a display as follows:

[Grafana display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkrwP.png)

What I'm aiming for is that the column 'NUTCase' appears on the left, 'AWS_Route53_DDNS' appears in the middle and as I add more repositories to monitor the number of displayed values does not rise above a limit (say 4)